# If URL has no extension then redirect to another website

Tags: url, redirect

I'm trying to redirect to an off the wall website if someone requests a page such as https://example.com/12qw34er56ty that has no extension. I came up with the code below but it doesn't work. Any suggestions? Thanks.

```
 RewriteRule ^[!/.]*([A-Za-z]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ https://wilqwhjk34er56ty.com [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer to my question. All my files are htm so I'm using this.

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.htm$
 RewriteRule ^([^.]+)((/)?)$ https://example.com [nc]
```